# go-redis HSet() struct with pointer fields

Tags: go, go-redis

I'm trying to HSet() structs with pointers.

Example:

```
cl := redis.NewClient(&redis.Options{
    Addr:     "localhost:6386",
    Password: "", // no password set
    DB:       0,  // use default DB
    PoolSize: 100,
})

type pointer struct {
    PtrInt *int    `redis:"ptrInt"`
    PtrStr *string `redis:"ptrStr"`
}

i := 1
s := "s"
p := pointer{&i, &s}

err := cl.HSet(context.Background(), "key", p).Err()
fmt.Println(err)

// redis: can't marshal *int (implement encoding.BinaryMarshaler)
```

How would you solve this? For some reason, the pointers are not dereferenced, thus I have to save like 30 different structs.

Thank you!

Edit: As pointed out in the comments, it seems like I have to implement the *encoding.BinaryMarshaler interface* for pointers to *simple data types* like *int and *string. How would you do that?

So far, my solution is:

```
func main() {
    cl := redis.NewClient(&redis.Options{
        Addr:     "localhost:6386",
        Password: "", // no password set
        DB:       0,  // use default DB
        PoolSize: 100,
    })

    type pointer struct {
        PtrInt *int    `redis:"ptrInt"`
        I      int     `redis:"int"`
        PtrStr *string `redis:"ptrStr"`
    }

    i := 1
    s := "s"
    p := pointer{&i, 1, &s}

    typ := reflect.TypeOf(p)
    val := reflect.ValueOf(p)

    for i := 0; i < typ.NumField(); i++ {

        // set only, if it's not a pointer
        if val.Field(i).Kind() != reflect.Ptr {
            err := cl.HSet(context.Background(), "test:1", typ.Field(i).Name, val.Field(i).Interface()).Err()
            if err != nil {
                t.Errorf("%s", err.Error())
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you have to store the pointers and not the values?

Comment: This is [documented](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/redis/go-redis/v9#Client.HSet) behaviour: *"For the type of structure field, __we only support simple data types: string, int/uint(8,16,32,64), float(32,64), time.Time(to RFC3339Nano), time.Duration(to Nanoseconds )__, ..."*. And, just like the error message suggests, the documentation continues: *"if you are other more complex or custom data types, __please implement the encoding.BinaryMarshaler interface__."*.

Comment: I want to store the values, not the pointers. It's all pointers to "simple data types". Im very stuck at implementing the encoding.BinaryMarshaler interface for *int, *string and so on.

Answer (score 1):

go-redis is not handling struct fields so good and [somewhere in it's tutorial it said](https://redis.uptrace.dev/guide/scanning-hash-fields.html):

> Because go-redis does not provide a helper to save structs in Redis, we are using a pipeline to load some data into our database.

You can try and implement the `encoding.BinaryMarshaler` for your type `pointer` and other types, but it is also time-consuming if you have so many structs with pinter fields.

My recommendation is to forget about `struct` feature of the `redisClient.Hset()` and try to use `map[string]interface{}`, so you have to convert your structs into `map[string]interface{}`. Hopefully this is implemented in many encoding libraries, like `json` or `mapstructure`. For your case, something like this works:

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "encoding/json"

    "github.com/redis/go-redis/v9"
)

type pointer struct {
    PtrInt *int
    PtrStr *string
}

func main() {
    ctx := context.Background()
    cl := redis.NewClient(&redis.Options{
        Addr:     "localhost:6379",
        Password: "", // no password set
        DB:       0,  // use default DB
        PoolSize: 100,
    })

    i := 1
    s := "s"
    p := pointer{&i, &s}

    data, err := json.Marshal(p)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    var inInterface map[string]interface{}
    err = json.Unmarshal(data, &inInterface)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    err = cl.HSet(ctx, "key", inInterface).Err()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

Comment: Im sure this will work, will check if it’s efficient though. I would like to avoid converting to json back and forth. The only reason I’m using pointers is because I’m receiving null values from MySQL. Maybe another way would be to implement the binaryMarshaller in there? Then I can use sql.NullString etc

Comment: @schlumpel then `mapstructure` is another option to just convert struct to the `map[string]interface{}`. Implementing the binaryMarshaller also has its own efforts, cause you can't use something like json marshaller inside it ( it doesn't consider redis tags ), and implementing that for all of your types is a pain.

Comment: I'm gonna look into this package, thank you! I just edited the question with a working solution. What do you think about it? (Will accept yours aswell, its working)

Comment: @schlumpel I should write a benchmark test to evaluate its efficiency, but this way you have a redis call for each field, not each struct. at least use redis.pipeline for all the fields for less network overhead.

Comment: @schlumpel I benchmarked your solution and the time is not in it.
`BenchmarkStruct-8          45493             24045 ns/op             384 B/op         14 allocs/op` + 
`BenchmarkMap-8             37438             28771 ns/op            1040 B/op         29 allocs/op` + 
`BenchmarkReflection-8              22920             46688 ns/op             544 B/op         23 allocs/op` 
first is the struct with no pointer field and letting the go-redis handle the case, second is my solution, and third is your reflection solution ( I ran 2 times each benchmark )